# Question on finite sets: The union of two set with $m$ elements and $n$ elements has $m+n$ elements

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $A$ has $n$ elements and $B$ has $m$ elements and are
> disjoint. Prove that $A \cup B $ has $n+m$ elements.

### Attempt:

Given that we can find bijections $f:  \{1,2,...,n \} \to A$ and $g :  \{1,2,...,m\} \to B$.

So, we know $f(1),f(2),...,f(n) \in A$ and $g(1),...,g(m) \in B$. If we define $h : \{1,2,...,n,n+1,n+2,...,n+m \} \to A \cup B $ in the following way:

$h(1)=f(1),...,h(n)=f(n)$ and

$h(n+1) = g(1),....,h(n+m) = g(m)$

Then all we will have to show is that it is bijective. First we show injectivity: Suppose $h(i) = h(j)$. Then, either $f(i) = f(j)$ in which case we will obtain $i=j$ since $f$ is injective or $g(i) = g(j)$ which yields the same. We disregard the case $f(i) = g(j)$ since $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

As for surjectivity, pick any $x \in A \cup B$, then either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. IF $x \in A$, then we know there is some $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ so that $h(i) = f(i) = x$. if $x \in B$, then there is some $j \in \{1,...,m \}$ so that  $h(j) = g(j) =x$.

IS this a correct solution? any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is correct. However, why wouldn't the following argument do?
$$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| = n +m - 0 = n+m$$

Comment: Principle of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: Seems to me that the principle of inclusion-exclusion comes logically after what the OP is trying to prove. Their next step along the course could easily be "Use this to prove inclusion-exclusion," so they are right not to use it in their proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly **correct** solution.

Well done!

Your proof is rigorous, and the mathematical arguments are correct.

Answer (score 1):

> As for surjectivity, pick any $x \in A∪B$, then either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. IF $x \in A$, then we know there is some $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ so that $h(i)=f(i)=x$. if $x \in B$, then there is some $j \in \{1,...,m\}$ so that $h(j)=g(j)=x.$

Everything about your proof is correct except for the part where you proved the function is surjective.

1. You need to state that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint to conclude $x \in A$ and/or $x \in B$.
2. Also, if $x \in B$ then there exists an $i \in \{n+1, n+2,..,n+m\}$ such that $h(i)=g(i-n)=x$.